# How to sort import in VSCode by using eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort?

Tags: eslint, prettier

Is it possible to sort imports (by using `eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort`) after applying `Format Document` (`Shift+Alt+F`) in Visual Studio Code?

Currently, it works only after running `eslint --fix`, but I would like to sort imports on document format.

P.S. `Format document` triggers prettier

Comment: The vscode-eslint extension’s readme mentions usage as a formatter or running fix on save: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint#version-204

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if your shortcut run prettier, I would go with prettier plugin
[@trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports).

You can add it to your project following way:

via npm

`npm install --save-dev @trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports`

or, using yarn

`yarn add --dev @trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports`

Then, you just need to setup sort rules in your `.prettierrc`, e.g.:

```
"importOrder": ["^@core/(.*)$", "^@server/(.*)$", "^@ui/(.*)$", "^[./]"],
"importOrderSeparation": false,
```

And, voilà

Detailed setup is described on plugin npm page linked in first paragraph.